# Slow bulk insert to Azure database

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

We are running an elastic pool in Azure running multiple databases, when running 1 of our larger imports this seems to take longer than we are used to. During these imports we ran at 6 cores as a test. All databases are allowed to use all cores.

On our local enviroment, it inserts about 100k records per second, however, the same dataset on Azure does about 1k per second (our vm) to 4k per second (dev laptop).

During this insert, the database only uses 14% log IO, 5% CPU and 0% DataIO.
When setting up a new database using DTU model in P2 we are noticing the same experience. **So we are not even hitting the limits of the database**

The table contains about 36 columns which are all required.

We have tried this using BulkInsert in the following way using different batchsizes

```
BulkConfig b = new BulkConfig();
b.BatchSize = 100000;
await dbcontext.BulkInsertAsync(entities, b);
```

As well as using standard EntityFramework addranges using smaller batches. We even went as far as using the manually written SqlBulkCopy methods, however all with no dice.

Now the question is mainly, is this a software issue? Are we running into issues in our AzureDB? Do we need to change the way we do Bulk imports?

Edit:

Attempted to run the import using the TempDB Setting in BulkInsert, however this also does not increase performance. LogIO is still at 14%.

Comment: Probably related [Transaction log rate governance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-logical-server#transaction-log-rate-governance)

Comment: How would this factor in into that we are using very little of the database itself? Even when scaling up beyond this we are not seeing an increase of throughput.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with that. Found such information in [this repostory](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/smartbulkcopy#notes-on-azure-sql)

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate through the dataset on the application layer, invoking a
   stored procedure for each row that will perform an INSERT/UPDATE
   action based on the existence of a record with a certain key. If the
   number of records to upsert is limited, this strategy may work well;
   otherwise, roundtrips and log writes will have a major influence on
   speed.
2. To minimise roundtrips and log writes and increase throughput, use
   bulk insert approaches like the SqlBulkCopy class in ADO.NET to
   upload the full dataset to Azure SQL Database and then execute all
   the INSERT/UPDATE (or MERGE) operations in a single batch. Overall
   execution times may be reduced from hours to minutes/seconds using
   this method.

Here, is a discussion related to same scenario: Optimize Azure SQL Database Bulk Upsert scenarios - [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/optimize-azure-sql-database-bulk-upsert-scenarios/ba-p/781075).

Comment: While i agree that doing a direct upsert might give issues, we are doing these imports to a Import table (which is empty on start) and run the update statements on the database itself using a SP. Included in this, is that the database is not even using 15% log, i doubt we are running into server limits as far as we can see.